# How to create a JSONModel class in Objective-C with same variable in two types?

Tags: objective-c, json, jsonmodel

I have a JSONModel class in Objective-C. I am initializing this with JSON returned by a server.

```
#import "JSONModel.h"

@protocol MyJsonMoodelClass

@end

@interface MyJsonMoodelClass : JSONModel

@property (nonatomic, strong)  NSNumber <Optional>  * idFilm;
```

This JSON contains a variable called `idFilm`, and sometimes is returned of type `NSNumber` but another is returned in array.

For exaple:

```
idFilm : 5
```

or

```
idFilm : [2, 5]
```

How could I control this and how could I have the same variable defined by two types, `NSNumber` and `NSArray`? Is possible control this?

Comment: You could set it to an NSObject which is superclass of both NSNumber and NSArray.  But this is not really a good idea in most situations as you'd always have to be checking which type it is before doing anything with it (`isKindOfClass`), and it doesn't naturally convert to JSON, in your case, without extra work.  Better would be to always use an array, and if you get a number, put that number in an array and use the array instead (ie, an array with only one element).

Answer (score 0):

if you override "set" method? something like this:

```
- (void)setIdFilm:(id)idFilm
{
    if([idFilm isKindOfClass:NSArray])
        ...
    else
        ...
}
```

I don't know if can work but can be a starting point